# Laravel 5 fails to load stream: no file or directory

Tags: php, laravel-5

I just loaded up a fresh instance of Laravel 5 and this is the error I get:

```
    $ artisan serve
PHP Warning:  require(C:\Users\jesde_000\Desktop\learning-laravel-5\bootstrap../
vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Use
rs\jesde_000\Desktop\learning-laravel-5\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Warning: require(C:\Users\jesde_000\Desktop\learning-laravel-5\bootstrap../vendo
r/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\je
sde_000\Desktop\learning-laravel-5\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\jesde_000\Desktop
\learning-laravel-5\bootstrap../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pea
r') in C:\Users\jesde_000\Desktop\learning-laravel-5\bootstrap\autoload.php on l
ine 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\jesde_000\Desktop\lear
ning-laravel-5\bootstrap../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') i
n C:\Users\jesde_000\Desktop\learning-laravel-5\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 1
7
```

I have had no problem in the past with Laravel 4 instances, but this error seems like it should be an easy one to fix but cant figure out how.  Does anyone have any insight on this?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use the `--prefer-dist` flag at the end of the line to install packages.  Therefore the vendors folder wasn't there at all.  Now works like a charm.